# BluetoothAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(address) crashes when moving to API 31 from API 30

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth

BluetoothAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(address) works OK up to API30, but with API31 and higher it crashes. No Exception thrown. Just bombs.

Any known fix?

Comment: Are you sure no exception is thrown? Can you show some code and debug output?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing:

You can no longer use DefaultAdapter, if you do it crashes. To get a valid adapter you must get one with:

BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothManager.Adapter;

Then it works fine.